# Using c++20 with gcc 10 is limited to c++17

Tags: gcc, c++20

When i try to set c++20 standard with gcc 10.3, it sets _cplusplus macro to 201709L

```
gcc -x c++ -std=c++20  -E -dM -< /dev/null | grep _cplusplus
```

outputs:

```
#define __cplusplus 201709
```

Getting gcc version

```
 gcc --version
```

outputs:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: 201709L > 201703L. What do you want exactly?

Comment: From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html 202002L. I suppose i shouod check __STDC_VERSION__ instead

Comment: @user17732522 it would make sense, but gcc/clang set the macro long before they implement the features. In this case, more relevant is the release date of gcc-10 compared to the expected value (which is a date) of `__cplusplus`. And as I noted, gcc-10 sets a different value if you ask c++17 or c++20, you can just check >17 instead of >=20.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Makes sense, I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 3):

> __cplusplus
> This macro is defined when the C++ compiler is in use. You can use __cplusplus to test whether a header is compiled by a C compiler or a C++ compiler. This macro is similar to **STDC_VERSION**, in that it expands to a version number. Depending on the language standard selected, the value of the macro is 199711L for the 1998 C++ standard, 201103L for the 2011 C++ standard, 201402L for the 2014 C++ standard, 201703L for the 2017 C++ standard, or an unspecified value strictly larger than 201703L for the experimental languages enabled by -std=c++2a and -std=gnu++2a.

As quoted in the gcc 10.3 [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.3.0/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros). Since C++20 is not complete in gcc 10.3 yet.

For who interested in the macro difference between `-std=c++17` and `std=c++20`, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/eGq5bM9Gb)